# How to predict Total Hours needed with List as Input?

Tags: machine-learning, optimization, regression, analytics, prediction

I am struggling with the problem I am facing:
I have a dataset of different products (Cars) that have certain Work Orders open at a given time. I know from historical data how much time this work in **TOTAL** has caused.
Now I want to predict it for another Car (e.g. Car 3).

[image]

Which type of algorithm, regression shall I use for this?

My idea was to transform this row based dataset into column based with binary values e.g. Brake: 0/1, Screen 0/1.. But then I will have lots of Inputs as the number of possible Inputs is 100-200..

Comment: As you describe the problem, the only info you have to make a prediction is the prior repairs of the same type....  sooooo, why don't you re-arrange or group your data by the repair type and just give out the average value for that type of repair?

Comment: Good idea, but since I have the TOTAL hours only, it is rather the combination of open work orders that determine the needed hours of work..

Comment: Ahhh.  I misunderstood what you meant by total hrs.  That data table is quite misleading.  You could do some kind of multi-factor regression to find what values for the individual jobs best explains the total work order price, as long as you have a "reasonably small" number of item types and a "reasonably large" set of jobs in total

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick idea using multi-factor regression for 30 jobs, each of which is some random accumulation of 6 tasks with a "true cost" for each task.  We can regress against the task selections in each job to estimate the cost coefficients that best explain the total job costs.

First done w/ no "noise" in the system (tasks are exact), then with some random noise.

A "more thorough" job would include examining the R-squared value and plotting the residuals to ensure linearity.

```
In [1]: from sklearn import linear_model

In [2]: import numpy as np

In [3]: jobs = np.random.binomial(1, 0.6, (30, 6))

In [4]: true_costs = np.array([10, 20, 5, 53, 31, 42])

In [5]: jobs
Out[5]: 
array([[0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1],
       [1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1],
       [1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0]])

In [6]: tot_job_costs = jobs @ true_costs

In [7]: reg = linear_model.LinearRegression()

In [8]: reg.fit(jobs, tot_job_costs)
Out[8]: LinearRegression()

In [9]: reg.coef_
Out[9]: array([10., 20.,  5., 53., 31., 42.])

In [10]: np.random.normal?

In [11]: noise = np.random.normal(0, scale=5, size=30)

In [12]: noisy_costs = tot_job_costs + noise

In [13]: noisy_costs
Out[13]: 
array([113.94632664, 103.82109478,  78.73776288, 145.12778089,
       104.92931235,  48.14676751,  94.1052639 , 134.64827785,
       109.58893129,  67.48897806,  75.70934522, 143.46588308,
       143.12160502, 147.71249157,  53.93020167,  44.22848841,
       159.64772255,  52.49447057, 102.70555991,  69.08774251,
       125.10685342,  45.79436364, 129.81354375, 160.92510393,
       108.59837665, 149.1673096 , 135.12600871,  60.55375843,
       107.7925208 ,  88.16833899])

In [14]: reg.fit(jobs, noisy_costs)
Out[14]: LinearRegression()

In [15]: reg.coef_
Out[15]: 
array([12.09045186, 19.0013987 ,  3.44981506, 55.21114084, 33.82282467,
       40.48642199])

In [16]:
```